# Instagram API to retrieve images based on search query

Tags: instagram

Is there an API to retrieve Instagram images based on a search query, and is there any limit to calling this API?

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options for searching Instagram using the API:

1. Search by tag (single tag only):
   https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_search
2. Search media in a given location:
   http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search

The API will limit you to 5000 requests per hour for a single Client_ID or 5000 requests per hour for individual Access_Tokens which require the user to be authenticated. You can also only retrieve around 20-30 images per request without because of pagination.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

First, register as a developer.
Then use this url:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/YOURTAG/media/recent?access_token=YOURACCESSTOKEN

after replace with your access token and your search term. it's 30 calls/hr max, so regulate : )

Comment: they increased to 5.000 requests/hour

Comment: negative. using ur app key will yield you 5000 req/hr, but using your access token yields 30req/hr. you can try 30 page reloads.